# How to make bash and make install use virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, bash, makefile

I've been trying to switch my coding to Linux.

I have ironed out most of my issues but one last thing I am not able to find any explanation of is the virtualization of make and bash commands.

I have installed PyCharm which virtualizes everything from what I have seen.
However, when I am cloning repositories from Github, the instructions require building some code using make and then installing them and later on using bash to build dependencies.

I am running the commands in PyCharm terminal but instead of installing into the venv, it's installing the data in /usr/xxx instead.

How do I tell PyCharm to use bash and make in a similar way to pip to virtualize the setup ?

Edit:
One of the projects in question is gym-gazebo which requires:

```
git clone https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo/blob/master/INSTALL.md
```

Then make and make install which installs it in the root

Later on there is also

```
bash setup_kinetic.bash
```

Which also uses root folders and not venv

I was able to install it but it is not virtualized the way it should when compared with coding on Windows

Comment: Pycharm has a way to create a virtual environment for a project during project creation, you can also select an interpreter from an existing installation for existing projects.

Comment: If you're required to use `make` to build (and install) the code, it's not a Python library, or a badly configured one. But libraries that get installed `/usr/xyz` can still be picked by Python executables running in virtual environments.

Comment: If you must (but probably not), there's generally a `--prefix` option to `configure` that allow you to point to a specific location. You can set the root of the virtual environment as prefix. But you'll also have to set environment variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH, hence I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Evert yes but in my case it requires adding the directory of the lib to do be able to use import but I want everything to go in venv if possible to not clutter things in the system and to make packaging easy

Comment: There isn't a generic answer to this. It depends on your specific project and its specific build system, and the very fact that you're having this problem at all implies that the build system *isn't* the simplest / most generic thing possible (ie. stock distutils). As such, this question doesn't presently contain sufficient details to permit an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have edited the question and added more details

Comment: What you're trying to achieve probably gets you close to (full) containerization, like Docker or Singularity. Alternatively, perhaps Conda can be of help here. I don't use it, but it tends to deal with external (non-Pyhton) libraries using local installs.

Comment: If you're specifically referring to Sophus, which is the only package that uses make (or rather, cmake) in the linked installation readme: you could ask a specific about how to install that locally. But there are cmake configuration variables you can specify on the command line to install in a local directory.

Comment: Maybe, be more kind, start to use linux in a regular way, instead of following tutorials, or install the half of github, first do some bash scripts, get used to user rights, scopes, etc. You peoples with all your fancies stuffs won't cease to amaze me. There is no need to install anything... everything else is futile..

Comment: @Cryptopat I've been using linux on and off for years but never had the reason to switch, I am familiar with it well enough but I just want to understand the containerization part what's wrong about that, you could've just not commented in the first place

Comment: virtualenvs are a Python-specific construct; they aren't made to contain things that aren't Python libraries. Insofar as your code depends on C libraries (not Python extensions written in C, but actual native C libraries that those extensions link to), those dependencies aren't something the virtualenv mechanism was designed to manage.

Comment: @Evert I didn't want to include specific github repo because I wanted to get the whole picture, now I'm researching containerization and I think that is what I was looking for

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay I think I got the picture, thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the answer based on Evert and CharlesDuffy, what I'm looking for is containerization, since the libraries I'm looking for are C based with a python wrapper (something like that)

Docker, Singularity and Conda are on of the solutions.